# accessing static C variables from inside asm volatile call

Tags: c, variables, assembly, volatile

When I try to access a static variable **directly** from inside an asm volatile call, I am getting an undefined reference error. I think there is a way to do this without using the input and output registers, but my searches are coming up empty.

```
int main() {
   static unsigned int a = 0;
   __asm__ __volatile__("push a" : : :);
   return 0;
}

error: undefined reference to a
```

Answer (score 2):

Really old question, but since there is no accepted answer...

First of all, let me say that using inline asm is usually a [bad idea](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  But if you must...

Since the static is declared inside a function, gcc needs some way to differentiate between a static variable named `a` in main(), and one in foo().  How it does this is implementation defined, but in a build on my machine, it used the name a.2499.  So using:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("push a.2499" : : :);
```

worked.  At least it did for a minute.  When I made some minor change to the surrounding code, it changed it to a.2500.  And of course shortly after executing this statement, the app crashed due to the corrupted stack.

But there are other problems with this approach.  Some of them come from this statement in the gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html):

> GCC does not parse the assembler instructions themselves and does not
>   know what they mean or even whether they are valid assembler input.

As a result, doing:

```
a++;
__asm__ __volatile__("push a.2500" : : :);
a++;
```

does not do what you expect.  Even the minimal optimizations from -O1 combine the two `a++` statements into a single `addl $2, a.2500(%rip)`.  It does this because the compiler has no visibility of the usage of `a` in the asm, something which using `a` as an input would provide.

You can 'kinda' work around this by declaring `a` as volatile.  And you can (probably) work around the naming problem by using a global.

But the best solution (if you really must use inline asm) is just to specify `a` as an input.  I see no benefits to the alternatives.

```
__asm__ __volatile__("push %0" 
  : /* no outputs */
  : "g" (a)  /* input as a register, memory, or immediate operand */
  : /* no clobbers, because there's no way to tell gcc we're unbalancing the stack and clobbering the red-zone */
);
```

Comment: Just a clarification: Your code comment discussing the red zone of course makes the assumption that you are actually even in an environment with a red zone.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("push " (a) : : :);
```

Comment: That seems to lead to a syntax error: expected ":" or ")" before "("

Answer (score -1):

dude,remove `a` from double quote

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("push " (a) : : :);
```